# Invalid column name error in database update statment

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server with a table made out of three columns named `barcode`, `package` and `lab`.
I'm trying to update the `lab` field of a specific `barcode` that I got as an input. This is what I've tried:

```
object[] args = { LabName, currentBarcode };
sql = string.Format("UPDATE BarcodesData SET Lab = {0} WHERE Barcode = {1}", args);
Adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
Adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error of "Invalid column name". The column name in the database is Lab so I don't understand what my mistake is but I believe it's something to do with the update statement.

Comment: Well, if `currentBarcode` and/or `LabName` are strings, your code isn't adding quotes - but don't fix that, use `SqlParameter` instead.

Comment: In other words, your final query might look like `UPDATE BarcodesData SET Lab = biology WHERE Barcode = S111000` - because the values aren't quoted, SQL thinks they are column names. Using SqlParameters makes sure your query is correctly formed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`). Without them, the arguments you're formatting into the SQL string will be interpreted as column names, and you'd get the error since there are no such columns.

You could quote the values:

```
sql = string.Format("UPDATE BarcodesData SET Lab = '{0}' WHERE Barcode = '{1}'", args);
// Here -------------------------------------------^---^-----------------^---^
```

But this is still a bad practice, and will leave your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks if these arguments are obtained from user input or any for of untrusted data.

A better practice would be to use bind variables:

```
sql = "UPDATE BarcodesData SET Lab = @lab WHERE Barcode = @barcode";
Adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lab", LabName);
Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", currentBarCode);
Adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: But we shouldn't be using [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score -1):

you have to do with Reserve
update tablename set [Lab]=1  where [Barcode]=1

Comment: Neither Lab or Barcode are [reserved words in Transact SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)